# Detect when duplicate queries are running in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an app that lets users search across many millions of records at once.  When the search does not return in a timely fashion, the users exit the app, log back in, and re-submit the search.

SQL server has no idea the user logged out and that it should not still be running the search, so I end up with many of the same query executing at the same time. Right now I just run a script that shows me what has been running for 5min or longer (mind you these searches are intense and can run for hours), how can i detect when duplicate queries are running?

Thanks,

Phillip

Comment: Exit the app and log back in? Why not offer them a Stop or Cancel button? Also, can you define what is a "duplicate query"? If I'm searching for "Suzie" and Suzie is searching for "Aaron" is that a duplicate?

Comment: Or sp_whoisactive. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/27/who-is-active-v11-00-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-27-of-30.aspx

Comment: Erm why doesn't the query get cancelled when they exit?

Comment: @Aaron, yes, a "stop" or "cancel" button would be useful, the devs have added it to their "backlog" :), duplicate is defined as "the same or different user executing the same search in the project".  The searches are "built" by selecting the index of items, adding conditions and sorting criteria, this is all saved as a search, the search can then be executed by 1 or several people depending on what items they are working on.

Comment: So where is that "search" stored? How do you know a user chose that search? Do you have a log or something that tells you a certain search was chosen? You could do this by logging at the beginning of the procedure, logging at the end, and any search more than n minutes old without an end log must have timed out / cancelled. SQL Server doesn't have any native functionality that will automatically track these searches you talk about.

Comment: Get them to cancel the query on exit, it will be way less work than trying to do this. If I was implementing this sort of functionality queries would be run by a service, and then the results persisted, then when you logged back they would be able to pick them up. Whoever designed this needs a slap.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this bit of SQL and check the text value:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

Credit to [Sql Authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/07/sql-server-find-currently-running-query-t-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

as @kell [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711345/1377943), with that query you can find longest running query,although it has some issues but if you read [this information](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/23/sql-server-2008-2005-find-longest-running-query-tsql-part-2/) you can also fix the known issues . 
Btw, i think why dont you left this job for sql-server. Sql server has inner capabilities to find query duplication , optimization and caching .. And it will be much better if you cached the result of the same sql query . 
 Microsoft has published best practice paper of sql-server-2008 caching . [Read it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) .